# How to query string inside a record in Google BigQuery? Docs not working

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to query a subset of a record in the bitcoin blockchain using the google bigquery database. I go here and click `view dataset` https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bigquery-public-data/bitcoin-blockchain. Then, on the left sidebar, it seems you have to click the dropdown at 'bigquery-public-data', then click 'bitcoin_blockchain' then 'transactions'. Then on the right you have to click the button 'Query Table'. This is the only way I have found to select the table -- just copying and pasting the command below won't recreate the error.

Based on the table that appears following the above instructions, I noticed that `outputs` are a`record` type. I would like to view only one `string` from inside the record. The string is called `output_pubkey_base58`.

So I read the docs, and the docs imply the command would be:

```
SELECT outputs.output_pubkey_base58 FROM `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions` LIMIT 1000;
```

I get an error: `Cannot access value on Array<Struct<output_satoshis ...` .. I tried `outputs[0].output_pubkey_base58`, didn't work

The annoying thing is that this problem is in the same format as the first example, where they query the `citiesLived.place` parameter from inside the `citiesLived` record in the same kind of command. : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/legacy-nested-repeated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `unnest` the array into a new variable.

```
SELECT o.output_pubkey_base58
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions`, 
UNNEST (outputs) as o 
LIMIT
  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel the confusion here is about legacy SQL and standard SQL. UNNEST must be used in standard SQL as described in document: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#differences_in_repeated_field_handling

Selecting nested repeated leaf fields
Using legacy SQL, you can "dot" into a nested repeated field without needing to consider where the repetition occurs. In standard SQL, attempting to "dot" into a nested repeated field results in an error.